# set.seed causes the same random numbers from exponential distribution with different parameter

Tags: r, random-seed

I observed the following behavior: when I set seed and draw random numbers from some distribution, e.g.exponential with `lambda=1`, I get the same numbers as when setting the same seed and using `lambda=10`, only 10 times higher:

```
set.seed(123)
rexp(10,1)
 [1] 0.84345726 0.57661027 1.32905487 0.03157736 0.05621098 0.31650122 0.31422729 0.14526680 2.72623646
[10] 0.02915345
set.seed(123)
rexp(10,10)
 [1] 0.084345726 0.057661027 0.132905487 0.003157736 0.005621098 0.031650122 0.031422729 0.014526680
 [9] 0.272623646 0.002915345
```

What I would expect is that different lambda, as the rate parameter, causes different distances between the individual numbers, i.e. different steepness of the exponential curve([Exponential_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)), no matter what the seed is.

Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Don't repeat the seed.

Comment: Rate is just a "magnitude" parameter.

Comment: Welcome to SO! @RomanLuštrik is absolutely right: the generator always produces samples from exponential distribution with `lambda=1`, and then multiplies by `1/lambda`, so the "core sequence" will always be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does cause different distances between numbers (10 times less in second case), which is clearly visible if you make a density plot of the data:

```
set.seed(123)
y1=rexp(10000,1)
set.seed(123)
y2=rexp(10000,10)
dt=data.table(x=c(seq_along(y1),seq_along(y2)),y=c(y1,y2),type=c(rep('a',times = length(y1)),rep('b',times=length(y2))))
qplot(data=dt,x=y,geom="density",col=type)
```

[image: Density plot of two exponential functions with different parameters]

I dont think there is any mistake here.